# How to use scrcpy with a server?

Tags: remote-access

is there a way to access an android via scrcpy and a server from anywhere?

I am looking for a way to help my parents around their android phones when I am not with them... I was wondering if I can broadcast the stream/screen from their phones via scrcpy to my server and view it on my PC or from the web, while not being on the same network?

This can be done with any solution, just that I can control the device remotely.

 It doesn't need to be `scrcpy`, it can also be some spyware tool or rootkit for all I care.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Questions about Android devices are not within scope.

Comment: scrcpy requires adbd running and authorized, that's kinda paradox to expect parents doing that all the time. server is physically located at parents home connected to same wifi?

Comment: @alecxs I am talking about a purchased VPS server that can act as a bridge for communication/sending data to it and viewing/controlling the device from it/web app.

Something like chrome remote desktop but as an apk/rootkit etc.

Comment: don't understand. but you should update your question with this information, so we can reject it back to superuser

Answer (score 0):

You could for example use
[TeamViewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/solutions/remote-desktop/android/),
free for private use.

Comment: Please do not answer off topic questions. You have been told this many times before.

Comment: @DavidPostill: I voted to migrate this question here. Now it's not off-topic.